# Dropping a directory from 'src' to 'dest' paths in Grunt.js and Assemble

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, assemble

I'm trying to take source files from `pages/*.hbs` and get them into the root of the `build` directory. Currently, they're ending up in `build/pages/*.html`.

Here's my task config. I tried looking into [Grunt's task configuration options](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) but wasn't getting any luck.

```
    assemble: {
        options: {
            layout: 'layouts/default.hbs'
        },
        pages: {
            src: ['pages/*.hbs'],
            dest: 'build/'
        }
```

Comment: What if you add a forward-slash? `dest: 'build/'`. Does that change anything?.

Comment: No, 'build' and 'build/' produce the same result. I've fooled around with `options.cwd` and `options.flatten` too but that just gets me errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `expand: true` which enables extra options, along with `cwd` which allows you to specify *but not include* part of your `src` path.

```
assemble: {
    options: {
        layout: 'layouts/default.hbs'
    },
    pages: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'pages'
        src: ['*.hbs'],
        dest: 'build/'
    }
```

[Building the Files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

Comment: That does it. Thank you!